# How to customize Textarea lines with Qml

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have simple chat application (socket.io) client on qml, i want to customize textarea lines (for coloring user messages) but i don't see anything about that for Qml.

So, I need help about that.
Best regards.

Comment: You have to clarify your question. What did you already try? What errors/warnings did you get? And yes, please provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As for the question - use [TextAreaStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-textareastyle.html) or `TextArea.textFormat: TextEdit.RichText` and html

Comment: I readed documents but i dont see anything, textedit richtext is my want. thanks for help, and i started make a new textarea self. for customize but now you solved.

Comment: @RequireBool, you didnt provide what code you tried ... what is the code of your chat application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you should to use HTML in your TextArea:

```
TextArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
    text: "<p style='color:blue'>line1</p><p style='color:green'>line2</p>"
    Component.onCompleted: {
        append("<p style='color:red'>line3</p>")
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand your cause to help, but the question lacks even an indication that the OP even started a QML project :)

Comment: Yes, you're completely right. But I noticed that OP has big problems even to explain the issue. As this problem is well known to me I tried to help.